# Shopify current_variant Variable Missing "fulfillment_service" property

Tags: shopify, liquid

For some reason in my product_variables template the current_variant variable does not have the "fulfillment_service": "amazon_marketplace_web" property available that I need to edit my code.

```
{%- assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant -%}
```

How can I get this added in?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fulfillment service is available on the `line_item` object once you complete the checkout process, a.k.a on the customer order page.

So long story short, you can't access the fulfillment service from the variant object directly.

Please refer to the description of the fulfillment process here: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/fulfillment in order to understand the meaning of it.

Comment: That seems really bad because I want to be able to tell my customers the expected shipping duration based on the fulfillment service available per variant / product.  Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @JasonBiondo how can you provide shipping details if you have different shipping providers for local and international delivery? ( you can't if you don't know the user location ) If you like a shipping calculator look into this article  https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Cart-Add-a-shipping-rates-calculator-to-your-cart/m-p/616576/highlight/true#M33